# Scan multiple files and format and copy to master file in VBA or Powerquery

Tags: excel, vba

I have some folders with hundreds of reports - all reports are the same, and there´s nothing else in that folders.
I should take multiple workbooks like the first one in the image, and recopilate them in a master file (second image).

[image]

I have some code - below - but I don´t know how to complete it; The workbook is a template, so it always have 15 rows (could be completed or not) and I need to bring all that´s there plus the date and group control, which is shared by every document inside the file.

I´d appreciate if you could help me complete the code; somebody told me this could be done using powerquery but I´ve never used it. If you think this would be easier, please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks!!

What I have:

```
Public Sub test()
'DECLARE AND SET VARIABLES
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Path As String
Path = "C:\Users\Maudibe\Desktop\ExcelFiles\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsm")
'--------------------------------------------
'OPEN EXCEL FILES
 Do While Len(Filename) > 0  'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
   Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
    '
    ' **WHAT TO DO HERE?** 
    '
     MsgBox Filename & " has opened"
    wbk.Close True
    Filename = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i modified your code to this: (Has to be in ThisWorkbook)

```
Public Sub test()
'DECLARE AND SET VARIABLES
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Path As String
Dim sht, msht As Worksheet
Dim lRowFile, lRowMaster As Long
Dim FirstDataSet As Integer

Path = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Files\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsm")
'--------------------------------------------
'OPEN EXCEL FILES
 Do While Filename <> "" And Filename <> "Master.xlsm" 'Dont Open MasterFile 'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)

    Set sht = Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets(1) 'First Sheet in File
    Set msht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 'First Sheet in Master

    lRF = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Last Row in File
    lRM = msht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Last Row in Master
    FirstDataSet = 5 'First Data Set in File

    For i = FirstDataSet To lRF
        lRM = msht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Last Row in Master
        msht.Range("A" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("A" & i).Value 'DocumentName
        msht.Range("B" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("B" & i).Value 'Amount
        msht.Range("C" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("D2").Value 'Date
        msht.Range("D" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("D3").Value 'Group #
    Next i
    wbk.Close True
    Filename = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

It will open the workbooks and check which rows are filled in Col A (Non used have to be blank). Then it copies the Data to the Master File. My Workbooks that have been opened looked like this and the Result:

[image]